# "Copyright and license headers should be defined" issue in Sonar 5.4

Tags: sonarqube

How to get rid of "Copyright and license headers should be defined"? Even after providing the header Sonar 5.4 gives error? Can someone give a sample header which is working for Sonar 5.4 ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a configurable rule, so look closely at the header you have configured. You don't say which language this pertains to, so I'll mention that in some languages it's possible to have the configured header evaluated as a regex while in others it can only be evaluated as an exact string match. Either way, this is a question of matching a pattern, and something as simple as a missing or additional space character could be what's throwing it off.

An online regex tester may be helpful to you in properly configuring the value for the rule.